# Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': Angular 11

Tags: html, angular, ng-class, angular10, angular11

I'm getting following error in my new Angular 11 app. Could not found any syntax errors.

```
core.js:6156 ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'ng-reflect-Dev Portal' is not a valid attribute name.
    at EmulatedEncapsulationDomRenderer2.setAttribute (http://localhost:8080/admin/vendor.js:62217:16)
    at setNgReflectProperty (http://localhost:8080/admin/vendor.js:38053:26)
    at setNgReflectProperties (http://localhost:8080/admin/vendor.js:38078:13)
    at elementPropertyInternal (http://localhost:8080/admin/vendor.js:38001:13)
    at Module.ɵɵproperty (http://localhost:8080/admin/vendor.js:42749:9)
    at DevMainHeaderComponent_Template (http://localhost:8080/admin/app-layout-layout-module.js:394:65)
    at executeTemplate (http://localhost:8080/admin/vendor.js:37594:9)
    at refreshView (http://localhost:8080/admin/vendor.js:37463:13)
```

My html template as follows,

```
<div class="row main-header-container">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8 col-xl-8 offset-lg-2 offset-xl-2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2 col-xl-2" [ngClass]="(isLoggedInUser === true)?'offset-lg-3 offset-xl-3':'offset-lg-9 offset-xl-9'">
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>English</option>
          <option>Finish</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS File as follows,

```
export class DevMainHeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  public isLoggedInUser = true;
}
```

If I removed ngClass directive it works, but I cant find any issue with ngClass syntax here, even I tried  hardcoded like this `[ngClass]="['first']"`, still getting same error.

This console error is not throwing with ng serve and working fine, only in prod it happens.

Comment: Please post a small demo code in Stackblitz. Especially `[ngClass]="['first']"` is perfectly ok (**unlike what the answers below say**). There must be something else in your environment that causes it.

Comment: Will provide a one soon

Comment: Can you show your code at https://stackblitz.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm building my project with maven, my project name is `<name>Dev Portal</name>`. It contains a space. This project name is adding as attribute. And attribute cannot contains space.

```
<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-Dev Portal": "true"
}-->
```

Removing space from name resolved the problem`<name>DevPortal</name>`
With Angular 9 this behavior was not there.

Comment: are you using frontend-maven-plugin, for de the build ?

Comment: yes , I fixed I removed the white spaces inthe name and it works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

If your are using a condition to determine a class you should use a different syntax like so:

```
[ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}"
```

Example:

```
[ngClass]="{'checked': rating > 0}"
```

https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried this way too, still getting same error.